# How to zero pad an f-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, f-string, zero-padding

Like this is how you can 0 pad a format string

```
for i in range(10):
   zeropad = "Value is{:03}.".format(i)
   print(zeropad)
```

and you get result as

```
Value is 000
Value is 001
```

and so on...

**So, how can i do the same thing with f-strings??**

I tried using the .zfill() function, but that doesnt work either

```
for i in range(1, 11):
  sentence = f"The value is {i(zfill(3))}."
  print(sentence)`
```

This gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    sentence = f"The value is {i.zfill(3)}."
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'zfill'
```

Comment: `f'... {i:03}'`…

Comment: This seems to be a good question, and not a duplicate. Padding integers with zeros is different from padding strings with spaces, and uses different f-string identifiers to do so. The correct answer (imo) of `f"The value is {i:03d}."` has not been posted here, and would not be posted in the "duplicate" string-related question.

Answer (score 3):

fix for your approach:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    sentence = f"The value is {str(i).zfill(3)}."
    print(sentence)
```

f-string approach

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    sentence = f"The value is {i:03}."
    print(sentence)
```

Comment: I got this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    sentence = f"The value is {i:03)}."
ValueError: Unknown format code ')' for object of type 'int'

Comment: You have an extra `)`